# self.navigationItem.titleView does not work with tabbed application template

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, ios7.1

I am new to developing for iOS, but I am completely stumped with this.

Steps:

1. In Xcode, create a new tabbed application for iPhone.
2. Go into first subview and drag a Navigation Bar to the view.
3. Go into viewDidLoad and add this (assuming you have dropped logo.png into the project structure):

`self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];`

Render the view - it does not work. No custom image replaces the default "Title" text.

I don't understand. Why does this not work? What do I have to do to make it work? Is there something fundamentally different I need to be doing or a concept I am not grasping fully here?

**UPDATE**

I have figured out that the code above works. You just need to embed your view inside a navigation controller. Click on the first tabbed view, then do `Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller`. The code will then work, and you can continue moving forward. Just embed each tab in a navigation controller using the method above and you should be good to go!

Comment: Did you add the files into the project folder and next set add new files in Xcode?

Comment: Yes, files are in the project folder. I have custom images for tabs that are working just fine.

Comment: The Xcode tag should only be used for IDE-related questions, not framework-related.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have will work if your controller is embedded in a navigation controller, but if you add a navigation bar manually, you need to make an IBOutlet to it (bar in my example), and get its navigation item,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINavigationItem *item = self.bar.items[0];
    item.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
}
```

Comment: When I add this code, I get this error: `Property 'bar' not found on object of type 'SHPaymentsViewController *'`

My view controller, `SHPaymentsViewController`, has this in its header file if this helps any: `@interface SHPaymentsViewController : UIViewController`

Comment: @Thomas, bar is an IBOutlet. You need to have that property in your header file (or in the class extension at the top of the .m file).

Comment: I have added this to my .h file for the subclass: `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *bar;`. That is what I would need to add, correct? Still no luck. :-( Thank you for your continued help with this - I'm about to pull my hair out!

Comment: @Thomas, and did you connect the outlet you created to the navigation bar in the storyboard? BTW, this (and most other) outlets should be declared as weak, not strong (since the outlet refers to a UI element that will be added to your view, the view keeps a strong pointer to it, so you don't need do).

Comment: I had to embed the view in a navigation controller and then it worked as expected. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem you are facing is because of not setting the frame. I face similar problem sometimes. Try this:

```
UIImageView *customTitleView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((320-210)/2, 0, 210, 50)];
customTitleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.navigationItem.titleView = customTitleView;
```

Hope this helps. :)